# Uploading a specific photo causes ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, large-files

I have a page on my website that I can upload multiple large photos to through an html form, processed with PHP. Everything works great - I am able to upload dozens of files at once (my max so far has been about 150).

However, there have been two separate instances where I got the dreaded ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error because of ONE image in the bunch. I don't think there is anything different about the image... it's the same file type and was taken on the same day by the same camera with the same dimensions and DPI.

I tried to upload that one image by itself, but I got the same error. [Here is the photo](http://crsocials.com/11_PeterDavid_015.jpg) for you to examine if necessary.

My php.ini file:

```
file_uploads = On
max_file_uploads = 300
max_execution_time = 999999
max_input_time = 999999
post_max_size = 80M
upload_max_filesize = 80M
memory_limit = 50G
```

What could be so different about this image that would cause it not to upload?

Comment: Is this a local project or is your site up on some hosted server?

Comment: Hosted on a Godaddy server

Comment: Checked the error logs for any symptoms? We can't do much about an error without more details.

Comment: Then there might be a limit on their part. From what I've researched so far the problem most likely is not in your PHP settings, especially if they are like you've mentioned. Checking the error log, as @MarcB mentioned would be the best way of finding a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, there were no error logs generated by the PHP, and the only errors in the server's error log are from when I was messing with the .htaccess (which I no longer have). I guess my next step would be to contact Godaddy and ask them if they have some kind of limit on their end?

Comment: Oddly enough, when I open the photo in photoshop and re-save it, it uploads fine. Maybe some kind of corruption when transferring the file from the camera to the pc?